# how to get number of rows effected as a numerical value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have this procedure to delete a row from table

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spConfiguration_test]
@ID int
AS

Declare @ERR int 
set @ERR = 0
DECLARE @Rows   int
SET @Rows  =0
begin tran

delete from de   where ClaimVersion=5 
    set @ERR = @@Error

    SELECT @Rows= @Rows + @@ROWCOUNT;

if @ERR = 0 commit tran
else rollback tran
```

I want it return a value like 1 or 2 or 3 depending on the number of rows deleted
but it gives me `(1 row(s) affected)`

what changes do I have to make?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the `sp` prefix on stored procedure names should be left for Microsoft's use.

If you want to have access to the flag that indicates whether or not rows were deleted then you probably want to add it as an output parameter.

Using a transaction to wrap a single `DELETE` statement isn't going to do much. I've left the transaction code in on the assumption that this is part of a larger procedure.

If you do have multiple steps within the transaction you may want to use `RaIsError` to indicate to the caller where a problem occurred and provide some application specific context, e.g. the arguments passed to the procedure.

You can also use `try`/`catch` in a stored procedure. Sometimes handy, sometimes clumsy depending on what sorts of operations you need to perform and how much you need to know about exceptions.

```
create procedure [dbo].[Configuration_test]
  @Id Int, -- Unused.
  @Deleted Int Output -- Flag: 1 if any rows are deleted, 0 otherwise.
as
  set nocount on

  declare @Err as Int = 0; 
  set @Deleted = 0;

  begin transaction;

  delete
    from de
    where ClaimVersion = 5;

  select @Deleted = case when @@RowCount > 0 then 1 else 0 end,
    @Err = @@Error;

  if @Err != 0
    begin
    rollback transaction;
    return;
    end;

  -- Next operation...

  set @Err = @@Error;
  if @Err != 0
    begin
    rollback transaction;
    RaIsError( 'Boo boo in step 42 processing Id %d.', 13, 42, @Id );
    end;

  -- Repeat operation/error check...

  commit transaction;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer +1,I will try as you suggested,I am deleting from 7 tables so I am using transaction but here I have an example of single table

Comment: @SpringLearner - The example is updated with improved error handling for multiple operations within a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Move the reference to `@@RowCount` immediately after the `delete`.  Or, combine the two assignments in one statement:

```
delete from de where ClaimVersion = 5 ;

select @Rows = @Rows + @@ROWCOUNT, @ERR = @@Error;
```

Comment: @SpringLearner - Then your delete statement is deleting only one row. How many rows you get when you run `Select * from de   where ClaimVersion=5`

Comment: yes its deleteing only one row but I want it as numerical value .actuallY i am executing this procedure using java like this public Integer deleteSublist(Integer subPartsId)
{
 String storedProcedure="exec spConfiguration_SubParts_Del "+subPartsId;
 System.out.println(storedProcedure);
 Query query=entityManagerUtil.entityManager.createNativeQuery(storedProcedure);
 return query.executeUpdate();
}

Comment: Moving it before would result in `@Err` always being `0`, as `@Error` has the same behaviour as `@@RowCount` in that it only applies to the item immediately previous.

Answer (score 0):

You can also `SET NOCOUNT OFF`.

Remarks

When SET NOCOUNT is ON, the count (indicating the number of rows affected by a Transact-SQL statement) is not returned. When SET NOCOUNT is OFF, the count is returned.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spConfiguration_test]
    @ID int
    AS

    Declare @ERR int 
    set @ERR = 0

   SET NOCOUNT OFF

    begin tran

    delete from de   where ClaimVersion=5 
        set @ERR = @@Error


    if @ERR = 0 commit tran
    else rollback tran
```

After SP Creation execute the SP As follows :

```
EXEC    [dbo].[spConfiguration_test]
        @ID = 0
```

Comment: it always says (1 row(s) affected) or (2 row(s) affected) etc,I dont want this way.I want a value like the value i get from Select count(*) from de where  ClaimVersion=5

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is that `@@RowCount` returns the number of rows affected by the previous statement.

In your case the previous statement is: `set @ERR = @@Error`

Try this instead

```
DELETE
FROM   de
WHERE  ClaimVersion = 5
;

SELECT @ERR  = @@Error
     , @Rows = @@RowCount
;

PRINT @Rows;
```

P.S. don't prefix your procedure names with things like "sp". It's as bad as prefixing all your tables with "tbl".

Comment: I dont know if you know java or not.if I use PRINT @Rows; then it just prints in the sql server console.I am calling this SP in a java method whose return type is integer.If 2 rows are deleted then it should return 2.

Comment: What's the vvalue returned in the SQL Server console? The print line is there to prove a point that you get the correct value, not for Java. Let's prove the SQL is correct first!

Comment: P.S. @SpringLearner by "return type is integer" do you mean: the stored procedure returns an integer value or an integer data set (even if that data set is a single value). The subtly is small but important.

Comment: the print line prints the number of rows deleted

Comment: my requirement is that stored procedure should return me a value 1 if atleast one row is deleted else 0

Comment: @SpringLearner - You mean `select @Rows = case when @@RowCount > 0 then 1 else 0 end;`? That will set a zero or one in the inappropriately named `@Rows`.

Comment: @HABO can you please post your answer so that I can upvote.Also please mention how to use,right now I am running **exec spConfiguration_test 5**